# Find all files which contain pattern in directory of tar files

Tags: tar, find, grep

I have all tar files in a directory. I want to find some files in tar files without extract all tar files.

I know how to work with one tar file:

`tar tvf abc.tar | grep xyz`

I want to find in all tar files but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that all of your tar filenames end in `.tar`.  And let's assume that you're looking for any file, within all of those tar files, whose name ends in `.dat`.  With these assumptions, you might then use:

```
$ for f in `find . -type f -name "*.tar" -print`; do tar tf $f | grep \.dat > /dev/null && echo $f; done
```

The `find` command is used to get the list of `.tar` files; you might end up with directories that contain files other than `.tar` files.  For each `.tar` file found, list its table of contents (`tar tf`), and `grep` that table of contents for names matching our pattern.

The example command above simply prints out the names of the `.tar` files which contain files matching our pattern; if you *also* wanted to see the names of matched files, then you might remove the `> /dev/null` part of the `grep` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used for loop with tar to solve my problem `for file in *.tar; do tar tvf $file | grep ABC_XYZ; done`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a small script for that task. Something like the following:

```bash
REGEX="my search string"

find . -type f -name '*.tar' -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' FILE
do
  # the sed command adds the filename prefix
  tar tf "${FILE}" | grep -- "${REGEX}" | sed "s|^|${FILE}: |"
done
```